# T-SQL query to select only rows which do not have a unique value in specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQLServer with the following three columns:

- RowID
- RMA
- Value

RowID is unique but RMA and Value are not.

I want to write a query that selects all rows from the table which share any particular RMA. So let's say we have the following three rows

```
ID  RMA   Value
1 - 222- Car
2 - 923 - Boat
3 - 222 - Plane
4 - 555 - Other
5 - 555 - Jet
```

I want a query that will return rows 1, 3, 4 and 5. Row 2 will not be selected because its RMA only occurs once.

I don't even know where to start for this. Do I need to use the `COUNT()` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
select * 
from your_Table
where RMA in 
    (
        select RMA
        from your_table
        group by RMA
        having count(RowID) > 1
    )
```

Inner query gives you RMAs what occurs more than once, and outer gives records having these RMAs.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this

```
select id,rma,value from yourtable where rma in 
(select RMA from yourtable 
group by RMA having count(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach with `exists` that doesn't require aggregation:

```
select * 
from yourtable y
where exists (
    select 1
    from yourtable y2 
    where y.rma = y2.rma and y.id != y2.id )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT RowID, 
        RMA, 
        [Value]
FROM (
    SELECT  RowID, 
            RMA, 
            [Value],
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY RMA ORDER BY RMA) as c
    FROM YourTable
    ) as p
WHERE p.c > 1
```

Output:

```
RowID   RMA Value
3       222 Plane
1       222 Car
4       555 Other
5       555 Jet
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE RMA IN
(SELECT RMA FROM TABLE GROUP BY RMA HAVING COUNT(*) >1)
```

You can use a nested query that consider only the row with COUNT of RMA > 1